# Can I use my B1/B2 visa to enter US right after I complete my OPT?

Tags: b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I am holding a F-1 and a B1/B2 visa. Can I enter the US right after I complete my OPT employment?

I am currently on OPT and it will end in coming November. Once I complete my OPT (F-1), can I leave and re-enter the US with a B1/B2 visa the next day? (or in a short time of period)

Comment: How long would you want to stay in B-1 or B-2 status?  What would the purpose of your visit be?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, yes, this is possible.  That is, there's no hard prohibition against it in the law.  But you will need to convince the immigration officer that you're entering for a legitimate reason and that you won't do any work or otherwise violate your B-1 or B-2 status.  This may be difficult if the officer suspects that your travel is an attempt to extend the grace period or to do something else that would be forbidden.

If you have a reasonable story, however, and don't plan to stay for very long, then you are unlikely to have problems.